# Translation Manager & SDL Language Cloud Integration

Tags: translation-manager, language-cloud

I'm working on building some Translation Manager extensions which I plan to release to the community. I had read online, and in the SDL documentation, that we can use the SDL Language Cloud for machine-translations of content sourced in Tridion and sent over to the Language Cloud via Translation Manager - which sounds ideal for development and demo purposes.

I had been attempting to sign-up for an SDL Language Cloud login, in order to generate the API key that we set in the publication properties - but I have been unable to find where the API key is generated.

- https://www.sdl.com/contact/language-cloud.html
- https://languagecloud.sdl.com/translation-toolkit/

[image]

Upon reaching out to SDL support, I was told:

> Thank you for contacting SDL Support.
>
> We have stopped offering the API Integration through Language Cloud Machine Translation.

I'm just wondering if others have managed to acquire an API key for development purposes (within the past few months). I understand it's been discontinued, but without the Language Cloud I am not sure how I can test out Translation Manager functionality and build community extensions as the other translation systems are not as simple to get setup with as was the Language Cloud translation toolkit.

I've responded to the SDL support and asked them if they can provide a key as it's for development purposes, so they may possibly oblige, but I wanted to pose the question to you all to see if there are any other options.